# How to define a struct which can may or may not have fixed fields

Tags: swift, xcode

This is the struct I am using and need your help in finding what will be the value of

**data** field.

```
struct ResponceData: Codable {
        let dataRes: [DataResStruct]
        struct DataResStruct: Codable {
            let data: <what should be used>
            let key: String
        }
    }
```

My responce data could be is like below:
Resp 1

```
{
    "dataRes": [{
        "data": [{
            "key1_d": "val1_v",
            "key2_d": "val2_v",
            "key3_d": "val3_v"
        }],
        "key": "1"
    }]
}
```

Resp 2

```
    {
    "dataRes": [{
        "data": [{
                "key1_A": "val1_B",
                "key2_A": "val2_B",
                "key3_A": "val3_B",
                "key4_A": "val4_B",
                "key5_A": "val5_B"
            },
            {
                "key1_C": "val1_D",
                "key1_C": "val1_D"
            }
        ],
        "key": "2"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described, this type is:

```
struct ResponceData: Codable {
    let dataRes: [DataResStruct]

    struct DataResStruct: Codable {
        let data: [[String:String]]
        let key: String
    }
}
```

Whether that's really the correct type, or if it is particularly useful, depends on how close the actual data you're parsing is to what you've posted here.

Comment: I missed the key field. Added back. Any suggestion on the struct you have shared.

Comment: That just adds the `key` field you described. `data` is still `[[String:String]]`, and array of dictionaries of string to string, assuming the values are really as you describe.

Comment: Thank you Rob Napier. `[[String: String]]` worked.

Comment: Is the below data declaration correct ?
`{data: {"key1_A": "val1_B", "key2_A": "val2_B", "key3_A": "val3_B" }}`
and the struct of data should be
`let data: [String: String]`

Comment: yeah. that's fine if the values are all strings.